# Kill Gridview Bind

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio, gridview

I have a Gridview that displays a huge list of products. On Client click of a select button in the grid I fill textboxes with the selected row's data. When i do this, I want to stop the Grid from Binding in Javascript. Is this a possible feat? Now the Gridview is in an updatepanel. Perhaps i could stop it from updating???

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited**
OR HOW CAN I STOP THE BINDING IN CODE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the click of the button i Set the Gridview's server side property 'Visible' to False. This kills the Databind.

Answer (score 0):

You can abort the postback by returning `false` from the onclick javascript function of your button.

Comment: No. This didn't work. Is there a way to stop the GRID at all javascript side? I know you can cause an update panel to update in javascript, but there is way to stop an update or a bind?